# how to do netbeans'"make controller" in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, netbeans

I use netbeans to make javafx applications. After I change some in scenebuilder and save to fxml, I switch to netbeans, right click the fxml and select "**make controller**" to add or delete some code in controllerclass.

Now I switch to intellij and found no way to do this. Is there a way to do this instead of manually copying codes generated by scenebuilder to controllerclass?

Comment: By copying code from Scenebuilder, do you mean from the "View -> Show Sample Controller Skeleton" menu in Scenebuilder?  That is the only way I know of.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean