# javafx: make controller in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, controller, fxml

I read this two article 
[IntelliJ, is it possible to “Make controller” as in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224993/intellij-is-it-possible-to-make-controller-as-in-netbeans)
[how to do netbeans'“make controller” in intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295321/how-to-do-netbeansmake-controller-in-intellij-idea)

can I make controller like netbeans in intellij idea?
I don't want to make controller from scene builder(View > Show Sample Controller Skeleton) and copy past to IDE
I want to make controller automatically

and I ask the same question [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237638)
[image]